# Moq - setup method with generic anonymous parameter

Tags: c#, generics, moq, anonymous-types

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public string ParseFile<T>(string filepath, T model)
```

As you can see, the model is a generic type. The method is called from the tested code like this:

```
var model = new
        {
            SubmittedBy = submittedBy,
            SubmittedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Changes = changes
        };
string mailTemplate = provider.ParseFile(filePath, model);
```

I supply a mock object for the *provider*. I need to fake the call of this method, to return the value I provide, i.e. I need something like this:

```
_mockTemplateProvider.Setup(
            x => x.ParseFile(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns("something");
```

When the test runs, the value I'm trying to set up is not returned. I can't use It.IsAny(), since the actual type is anonymous. If I try calling the method with an actual instance of *object* in debugger, it works. But how do I convince it to take an anonymous object? Or just don't care about arguments at all?

Comment: Can't reproduce (VS2015, Moq 4.2.1510.2205), the mock returns `"something"` as it was setup to do.  Try creating an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if you still see the problem. It's possible there's something else that's causing the issue here.

Comment: Can reproduce with Moq 4.0.10827 in VS 2013. Gist here of my code: https://gist.github.com/thomaslangston/46734b4577d1d3eac8c9d2c331f9e278

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous type is still an `object`, and the setup method you posted should be matched. Here is a working example

```
public interface IThing
{
    string DoIt<T>(T it);
}

public class Subject
{
    ...

    public string Execute()
    {
        var param = new
        {
            Foo = "bar",
            Baz = 23
        };
        return _thing.DoIt(param);
    }
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var mockThing = new Mock<IThing>();
    mockThing.Setup(t => t.DoIt(It.IsAny<object>()))
        .Returns("expectedResult");

    var subject = new Subject(mockThing.Object);
    var result = subject.Execute();

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("expectedResult"));
}
```

You can also capture the object that is passed into the mock and perform assertions on it using a `dynamic` + the `Callback` method.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    dynamic param = null;

    var mockThing = new Mock<IThing>();
    mockThing.Setup(t => t.DoIt(It.IsAny<object>()))
        .Callback<object>(p => param = p);

    var subject = new Subject(mockThing.Object);
    subject.Execute();

    Assert.That(param.Foo, Is.EqualTo("bar"));
    Assert.That(param.Baz, Is.EqualTo(23));
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. Here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/thomaslangston/46734b4577d1d3eac8c9d2c331f9e278

Comment: You're right it doesn't work with Moq 4.0! After a quick test, earliest version that it does work with is 4.1.1308.2321.